# onSuccessListner after image crop permission

Tags: android, imageview, crop

I am getting image cropping like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

//do some activity based on permission granted or declined.
            } else {
                CropImage.activity(mainImageURI)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .setAutoZoomEnabled(false)
                        .start(this);

                ;


            }

        }
```

My question is I want to do some activity right after the permission is granted or declined. In current scenario, I can first grant the permission and then again click again the imageview I am using, and then the cropping. But I want to have one activity right after the permission is granted and one if permission is denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `onRequestPermissionsResult` in your activity in order to get notified whenever permission is granted or not:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_CODE) {
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];
            int grantResult = grantResults[i];

            if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO Open The Crop Activity
                } else {
                    // TODO Tell the user your app can't function properly 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```